# calculate standard deviation and generate N random number between 2 numbers

Tags: python, normal-distribution

I want to generate a random normal distribution between 0 and 1 recursively. I can generate them if I know the mean, standard deviation (taking an approximation) and size by using something like np.random.normal(size=600, loc=0.5, scale=0.153). The catch is I have to be careful while giving the standard deviation so that the distribution remains between 0 and 1. But is there any way I could generate them if I only know the size and the mean.
My input is only the size N, mean = 0.5 and starting and end points i.e 0 and 1 between which I want to generate the numbers. Could someone please help?
What I have done so far is as below:

```
rng_seed = np.random.default_rng(12345)
for i in range(2):
    a = rng_seed.normal(0.5, 0.153, 601)
    b = np.random.normal(size=600, loc=0.5, scale=0.153)
    plt.hist(a)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Share your code.

Comment: a normal distribution isn't bounded. you could use a truncated normal, e.g. [`scipy.stats.truncnorm`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.truncnorm.html), but the scale parameter of this distribution corresponds to the standard deviation of a standard normal (not truncated) so if your stddev was estimated from the constrained sample the distribution might not be quite right. If that doesn't fit the bill, you'd probably have more luck on [stats.se] - technically you can't just ask for implementation recs on SO. See [ask].

Comment: thanks @Dhruv - please edit your question to include all the necessary information as [formatted code blocks](/help/formatting), don't provide it in comments. Thanks!

Comment: also, this is the code to produce a (non-constrained) normal distribution; LuisAlejandroVargasRamos is correctly asking you to show us what you have tried in terms of addressing your question. If this really is a stats theory question then it's not appropriate for this site and you can ask on [stats.se].